# A question about Linear normed spaces.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $E$ be a linear normed space. Let $A$ an open set in $E$. I have to prove that there is a family (countable) of closed sets in $E$ such that the union is $A$. And that if i have $A$ closed then is the intersection of open sets.

**Pd:** All my attempts have failed. Im stuck and tomarrow have my test.

Comment: In the finite dimensional case, this is clear, since $E$ is isomorphic to some $\mathbb{R}^n$ where the statement is easy to check.

Comment: Yes but im working in infinite dimensional case too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true in any metric space. Assume $A$ closed. Let 
$$
A_n=\bigcup_{a\in A}B_{1/n}(a),
$$
where $B_r(a)$ is the ball of of radius $r$ around $A$. It is clear that $A_n$ is open for all $n$, and that $A\subset A_{n+1}\subset A_n$.

Now we need to check that $A=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$. Suppose that $b\in A_n$ for all $n$. This means that for every $n$ there exists $a\in A$ with $b\in B_{1/n}(a)$. So the distance from $b$ to $A$ is zero. As $A$ is closed, $b\in A$. So we have proven that when $A$ is closed there exist open sets $A_n$ such that 
$$
A=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n.
$$

Now if $A$ is open, we can apply the previous part to $E\setminus A$. This is a closed set, so by the first part there exist open sets $B_n$ with 
$$
E\setminus A=\bigcap_nB_n.
$$
Let $A_n=E\setminus B_n$. As the complement of the intersection is the union of the complements, we get that
$$
A=\bigcup_n E\setminus B_n=\bigcup_nA_n,
$$
where the $A_n$ are closed.

Comment: Thanks i think i recently see your solution to other question.